# How to apply curveType option to google-chart element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to apply curveType to google-chart element to smooth the lines, but I get following error:

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined ×

Here is my code:

```
<google-chart
    type='line'
    options='{
        "title": "Days in a month",
        "curveType": "function" // curveType: "function"
    }'
    cols='[{"label": "Month", "type": "string"},{"label": "Days", "type": "number"}]'
    rows='[["Jan", 31],["Feb", 28],["Mar", 31],["Apr", 30],["May", 31],["Jun", 30]]'>
</google-chart>
```

If this is not the right way to to it, could anyone tell me how to curve the lines for polymer google-chart element?

Reference for curving the lines:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title is part of chart, not a first level option. Try:

```
<google-chart
    type='line'
    options='{
        "chart": {
             "title": "Days in a month"
        },
        "curveType": "function" // curveType: "function"
    }'
    cols='[{"label": "Month", "type": "string"},{"label": "Days", "type": "number"}]'
    rows='[["Jan", 31],["Feb", 28],["Mar", 31],["Apr", 30],["May", 31],["Jun", 30]]'>
</google-chart>
```

Comment: It would help to have an explanation. Why does your answer fix the error?

Comment: Title is part of chart, not at first level of options.

Comment: @Patricklaf it perfectly works! Is there documentation mentioning that title is part of chart? If you follow the reference link, they are all at the same level of options. I thought google-chart element just encapsulates Google Charts.